# ¿Como creo un evento keyup() al input type text de "prompt dialog" de alertity?

Tags: javascript, jquery

No encuentro como hacer el selector del campo que uno indica, es para validar el dato introducido.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#agregar', function() {
  alertify.prompt( 'Ventaja', 'Mensaje:', ''
    , function(evt, value) {
      alertify.success('You entered: ' + value)
    }
    , function() {
      alertify.error('Cancel')
    });
});

$( ".ajs-input" ).keyup(function(){
 console.log('se ejecuta el key-up');
 console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.10.0/alertify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.10.0/css/alertify.min.css">

<button type="button" id="agregar" name="agregar" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas bien, pero tienes que mover el evento adentro de tu función, de lo contrario como lo tienes al querer crear el evento tu objeto de alertify ya no existe por lo que este no funcionaría.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#agregar', function() {
  alertify.prompt( 'Ventaja', 'Mensaje:', ''
    , function(evt, value) {
      alertify.success('You entered: ' + value)
      $('.ajs-input').off('keyup');
    }
    , function() {
      alertify.error('Cancel')
      $('.ajs-input').off('keyup');
    });
    $( ".ajs-input" ).keyup(function(){
     console.log('se ejecuta el key-up');
         console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.10.0/alertify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.10.0/css/alertify.min.css">

<button type="button" id="agregar" name="agregar" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
```

Comment: Bien, gracias por tu respuesta, no se me ocurrio, pero hay un problema, el evento se repite cada vez q se ejecuta el boton "agregar".

Comment: Si, cuando le das 'agregar' hay que quitar el evento para que no se vayan apilando, ya lo agregué a mi respuesta `$('.ajs-input').off('keyup');`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :D